# Using "what" as a noun or object

Tags: objects, what

I saw a sign outside a factory office that said:

> If you don't have what to do, don't do it here.

I've also heard this word usage in the phrase:

> Do you have what to eat.

Is this grammatical or colloquial? I usually see the word "what" as introducing a question. Does it have another usage as a noun or object?

Comment: Using *what* for *anything* is still a pronominal use not a nominal one.  You can tell because you can't use it in the noun slot of a noun phrase: **"My three red whats are ready for you now"* You may wish to edit your question.

Comment: I can't find it in the online dictionaries I checked, but *what* can be used in these idioms to mean *something*. But if you check the dictionaries, you'll see that there are many other uses that don't introduce a question.

Comment: These examples appear to have been poorly translated from another language. I believe the correct translation would be: "*If you have nothing to do, don't do it here.*" and perhaps "*Do you have enough food?*" (there are more options here, depending on the exact context). -- Curiously enough, the phrase "*if you don't know what to do*" passes, unlike the very similar "*if you don't have what to do*".

Comment: Hi @michael.hor257k. Can you elaborate on your last sentence? I don't understand why the first passes while the second is problematic.

Comment: @DanF If I knew why, I would have posted this as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is the the definition and the function of "what" according to oxford learners dictionary 
( http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/what?q=What) 
what is pronoun,determiner
< it can be used in questions to ask for particular information about somebody/something, for example:

- What is your name?
- What (= what job) does he do?
- What time is it?
- What kind of music do you like?

or it can be the thing or things that; whatever, for example:

- What you need is a good meal.
- Nobody knows what will happen next.
- I spent what little time I had with my family.

Or it can be used to say that you think that something is especially good, bad, etc. For example:

- What awful weather!
- What a beautiful house!

I think the example of *'nobody knows what will happen next'* explains your query as 'what' might refer to certain thing which might be a noun or an object.

Comment: None of those is parallel to the examples in the question.

Comment: His example is "do u have what to eat"  is parallel ti mine "nobody knows what happens next"  as in both "what" refers to an object

Comment: The difference is that _know_ can take an indirect or reduced question as its object; _have_ cannot.